# Is Chazaq Chazaq v'nitchazeq חזק חזק ונתחזק an interruption for the reader? 

Tags: blessing, torah-reading, hefsek-interruption

Is it considered a hefsek for the Ba'al Kore to say חזק חזק ונתחזק, and, if it's not an interruption, is there a different problem because he is saying something which is not written in the Torah?

Comment: Are yoy talking about where the Ba'al Keriyah is the Oleh as well? Otherwise what is he being mafsik?

Comment: Even if he isn't the oleh, is there be a problem if he is saying something (other than amen to the oleh's bracha) which isn't written in the torah?  I was assuming that the oleh does not say חזק חזק ונתחזק in any event.

Comment: That's your second question, which is a good one. I'm not seeing the first question unless he is the Oleh himself.

Comment: I guess I always thought that since the ba'al koreh is the agent of the oleh, even if he wasn't the oleh, this could be considered a hefsek.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is it worth asking the question in the case where the Ba'al Keriyah is the Oleh as well?

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Moshe Stern ("The Debreziner") in [Shaalos U'Teshuvos Beer Moshe 3:28:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14710&st=&pgnum=41&hilite=) says that the one getting the Aliyah should not say Chazak as it is an interruption.

However, per [Otzar Minhagei Chabad](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&hilite=c20194b6-dabc-4ee5-8273-966a74565891&st=%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7+%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7+%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7&pgnum=394) everyone says Chazak including the one who got the Aliyah.